# Why does counting an empty string return 1?

Tags: php

*I realise `strlen` is the correct function to use, I'm just curious as to why this happens.*

How come if PHP in I do `echo count("");`, it returns the value 1?

[See example](https://ideone.com/h7LhnJ)

I'd have expected it to return `0`, as opposed to `1`.

Comment: Sure you're not looking for strln?

Comment: try reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: `count` is for the number of elements of an array. `strlen` is for the number of characters in a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

count is counting how many element there are. Here you got a string, so one element.

Please [read the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) :

> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Comment: Doh! I don't know how I missed that ◉_◉

Comment: Note that PHP7.2 onwards will now emit a warning if the value being supplied is not countable, i.e. is not an array or object, though will still give the same 'count' as before. See example 1 at https://php.net/count#example-6224.

Answer (score 6):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) says

> If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented
>   Countable interface, 1 will be returned.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, as a consequence of this:

```
var_dump((array)"");
```

... printing this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

See [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for the dirty details. The [official answer](http://php.net/count) is that `1` is simply the documented return value:

> If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented
>   Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if
>   array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.